# Varios tipos de datos en un arreglo c++

Tags: c++

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de meter varios tipos de datos en un arreglo, he visto que en otros lenguajes si se puede pero en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no tengo idea, he buscado y buscado pero no encuentro nada, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: La respuesta es no. Pero puedes meter un dato que pueda representar otros.

Comment: Preséntanos un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer y te diremos si es posible y cómo podrías hacerlo

Comment: string a[5];   int numero; char letra;, quiero meterlos al array aunque sean distintos, me imagino que la única manera seria convirtiendo a String

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade ahí el código. De la misma manera sería interesante que indicases si es un grupo cerrado (un grupo finito y limitado de tipos) o abierto

Comment: no tenia código, solo era una pregunta, si era posible o no, y si alguien sabia pues me ilustrara

Comment: El problema que tienes en C++ es que en algún momento tienes que saber qué tipo de dato tienes realmente almacenado para poder usarlo, por eso te digo, si es un conjunto finito de elementos ... alguna solución hay, si quieres almacenar _cualquier cosa_ en el sentido literal... no va a poder ser

Comment: lo que hice fue pedirlos en diferentes datos y convertirlos a string, y ya

Comment: puedes usar  el "tuple" que te soporta varios  tipos de datos. Es un template del std. Es tamaño fijo pero lo puedes  meter a  un vector. Lo otro es  con  un  arreglo de  punteros.

Answer (score 1):

> Quisiera saber si hay una forma de meter varios tipos de datos en un arreglo

No, los arreglos son una colección de un solo tipo de dato, por eso su definición tiene este aspecto:

```
Tipo nombre[tamaño];
```

Observa que sólo se especifica un tipo de dato: `Tipo`, ese tipo será el de todos los elementos del arreglo. Pero aún con esta limitación existen varias maneras de guardar múltiples tipos de datos en un arreglo, pero todas incluyen conocer de antemano qué tipos de datos vas a guardar.

1. **Subtipado**: Usa una jerarquía de clases para definir múltiples tipos de datos pero guarda en el arreglo la clase base:

   ```
   #define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

   struct Base { virtual void f() = 0; virtual ~Base() = default; };
   struct Derivada1 : public Base { void f() { P; } };
   struct Derivada2 : public Base { void f() { P; } };

   // ...

   Base *arreglo[] { new Derivada1, new Derivada2 };

   for (const auto &dato : arreglo)
          dato->f();
   ```

   El código anterior [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##jZBPS8NAEMXP2U8xULCJWNAek7QH/4GXGiQeRCVMdzdlYbsbNrPxEOpXj5tgK4IHLwPzeO/3huFNs@AazW4YZspw7YWEXNmWnMT9mrGZkLUyEgpoSaQpt54gz6Gqiqe7snyp7p83N@XD46aqRnn@ZuaMhbDnBNfYSuihU448auisElDHCazgMjupn6NrEkMRek0ZHLIj4VY61aHAK0ih8Vut@Al6hPVQhMQfmeV/MkwZgj0qEyesZ9FkPEfn5E7b1/dgNPLj54qLX@tyAkS1dRBza1oC9GThTGCYKXxTEhZFo7JYh@bR7yR5Z8IL2GEYvgA):

   > ```
   > virtual void Derivada1::f()
   > virtual void Derivada2::f()
   > ```

   Lo que nos demuestra que hemos guardado dos tipos de datos (`Derivada1` y `Derivada2`) en el arreglo pero el tipo de dato del arreglo se ha mantenido (el arreglo es una colección de `Base *`). Si usas código así, no olvides hacer `delete` de los punteros al acabar, o mejor: usa [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).
2. **Usa `std::variant`**: Esta clase puede contener múltiples tipos de datos (aunque sólo un tipo de dato puede estar activo), pero deben especificarse en tiempo de compilación.

   ```
   using tipo = std::variant<std::string, int, char>;

   struct visitor
   {
       void operator()(const std::string &s) { std::cout << "Cadena: " << s << '\n'; }
       void operator()(const int &i) { std::cout << "Entero: " << i << '\n'; }
       void operator()(const char &c) { std::cout << "Caracter: " << c << '\n'; }
   };

   // ...

   tipo arreglo[] { {std::string{"Cadena"}}, {0xfabada}, {'X'} };

   for (const auto &dato : arreglo)
       std::visit(visitor{}, dato);
   ```

   El código anterior [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##jZFLa4QwFIXX5ldcLPhgHBi6VMdN6X8otF3cxugEnETykILkr9cmo6VCW@gmj8PJxzk3dByPdEDRL8sdF3SwLYOaS20Uw2tDvrUJFUdh9pI3cdE3hFjtdzB8lHAGbdqy3Nz17bL6CuDCFEAvqJqKEC9aamDimhupyEyiSfIW5MgUeiHLMyqFNrAjQKJzmFeFSmugriF@wJYJLCEONx2W9EWkFbi/gD4FJPwn6FEYpuQG4v8AhSaQ0N8iKaQetrHonuV89ZDgilxkeah9GxsqxfpBPr962LyrPG/9YucKmE/vHb5hi@GcPqUOAi3qpIItElojIWl9TCi/mDmJovVPwqizbeCzZwRfHgiKGasEnCriluWDdgP2ejn6R2d6ONzjJw):

   > ```
   > Cadena: Cadena
   > Entero: 16431834
   > Caracter: X
   > ```

   Lo que nos demuestra que hemos guardado varios tipos de datos (`std::string`, `int` y `char`) en el arreglo pero el tipo de dato del arreglo se ha mantenido (una `std::variant` cerrada sobre esos tipos). El objeto `visitor` es opcional, puedes usar las funciones de [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) para leer o escribir datos.

- **Existe la opción de usar una `union`**: No la voy a explicar porque la segunda opción es una alternativa más segura.